# Change background size depending on width/height

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I use Simple Masonry gallery plugin on my WordPress website. It shows the images as a background of darkbox div.

Everything works fine in desktop version but the problem occurs in mobile version with one image with great height and very thin. I set the background size with percentage but it doesn't help - either the image is cut and goes out of page or it fits (background-size 60%) but the rest of images are really small.

I don't want to use background-size: contain, because I need some space, kind of border.

And the questions is:
how can I change the background-size with jquery for example when:
height is 2 as big as width? or 3 times as big as width?

Is there any solution?

This is the image of how it should be (and should work with smaller image):

[image: This works fine]

and this is how it looks with a bigger image:
[image: This is the image that makes the problem]

And this is the code for the background:

```
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
left: 0 !important;
top: 0 !important;
background-size: auto 80% !important;
z-index: 999999999999;
```

The width and height need to stay the same as the div has to cover the background.

Comment: Can you please add some code? We can't debug what we don't have.

Comment: Here you are the link, I think that's the easiest way to check it http://marcin-szewczyk.com/ but remember it's just the mobile version

Answer (score 0):

You can use "window" object to do this `$(window).width() / $(window).height()`. With this you can get width and height of the page. After that you can calc something and use this: http://api.jquery.com/css/ - `$('someobject').css( background-size, something )`

And remove !important from the css. Its bad...

Comment: But will I be able to set the size of background just in one case when the height is more or less twice as big as width?                                                   

And I know with !important but it's to prevent the css for element selector made by the code of plugin

Comment: `if( ($(window).height()*2) === $(window).width() ) { 
   $('someobject').css( background-size, something )
}`

Something like this.

Comment: I wrzucić to np. w footer jako <script> ?

Comment: Tak, do footer jako script. Powinno działać. (small translation: Yes, to footer as script. It should work)

Comment: The problem is that it occurs just in one case: when div id="darkbox" has background image with much greater height than width, in other cases there is no problem. And the gallery is displayed that #darkbox gets background image so I just need to set that with bg image larger 2x height, background size is changed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous comment in Polish. I used that. The code is:

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
if( ($(window).height()*2) === $(window).width() ) { $('#darkbox').css( background-size, 50% ) }
};
</script>`

However, still doesn't work right. Have a look - [The background size still isn't right, not 50% as set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlNp0.jpg)

The problem is, there are many pictures and with that particular one I need to change the background size, the others work properly with my css settings